# Why does the array store different unwanted numbers in the given problem?? This causes false outputs

Tags: arrays, c, function, output

I want to use the memcmp() function in the program. But unwanted numbers get stored in the arr4 array variable when I assign it values passed from another function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int print(int arr4[], int arr5[], int arr6[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}, arr2[4] = {5, 6, 7 ,8}, arr3[4] = {9, 10, 11, 12}, arr4[4], value;
    arr4[3] = print(arr1, arr2, arr3);
    arr4[2] = 5;
    printf("\n\nElements in arr4 array: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr4[i]);
    printf("Press Enter...\n");
    getchar();
    value = memcmp(arr4, arr3, 4 * sizeof(int));
    printf("\nThe value is: %d\n", value);
    if(value == 0)
        printf("\nThe arr3 and arr4 are the same!!!\n");
    else if(value < 0)
        printf("The arr3 is greater than arr4!!!\n");
    else if(value > 0)
        printf("The arr4 is greater than arr3!!!\n");
    printf("\nDone with the print program!!\n\n\a");
}

int print(int arr4[], int arr5[], int arr6[])
{
    int num[4];
    memcpy(num, arr4, 4 * sizeof(int));
    printf("The First 4 numbers stored: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
    printf("\nThe second set of numbers stored: \n");
    memcpy(num, arr5, 4 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
    printf("\nThe third set of numbers stored in the array: \n");
    memcpy(num, arr6, 4 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
    return num[3];
}
```

Output:

```
The First 4 numbers stored: 
1 2 3 4 
The second set of numbers stored: 
5 6 7 8 
The third set of numbers stored in the array: 
9 10 11 12 

Elements in arr4 array: 
-465963304 32766 5 12 Press Enter...


The value is: 207
The arr4 is greater than arr3!!!

Done with the print program!!
```

-465963304 32766 these are the unwanted numbers that get stored and cause problems in the program output. Why do these come? Also, when I compile and run it the second time, -465963304 changes to another number: -408901928 and keeps changing when I compile and run it another time...

However, when I pass the arr4 array variable to the void function print(), the output comes as desired...

What is the problem with the first version of the program?
In addition to these, when I return num[4], the suggestion comes as

```
warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    return num[4];
           ^   ~
note: array 'num' declared here
    int num[4];
    ^
```

But there is no warning when I have it as return num[3].
Why does this happen?

Comment: You don't initialize all elements of `arr4`, which means those elements will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Where in your code do you think you ever set `arr4[0]` and `arry4[1]`?

Comment: And you do remember that array indexes are zero-based? Which means that an array of `X` elements will have valid indexes in the range of `0` to `X - 1` (inclusive). So for an array of `4` elements the index `4` is out of bounds, as the max index is `3`.

Comment: @kaylum, arr4[3] = print(arr1, arr2, arr3); would do the job of initialising arr4[0] and arr4[1], right??

Comment: How can setting `arr4[3]` possibly set `arr4[0]` and `arr4[1]`? If you set index 3 of an array it does not change index 0 and 1 in any way.

Comment: @Prats No, index 3 is not index 0 nor index 1... hence the different numbers.

Comment: @kaylum, the output of the program also had arr4[3] initialized to 12. So I concluded that way...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. `arr4[3] = print(arr1, arr2, arr3);` in that code the `print` function returns `12` and then that gets assigned to array index 3. So of course array index 3 is 12 when it is printed. But that has nothing to do with the other array indices.

Comment: @kaylum I understood what you meant....Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are not initialize arr4 array,so the value storage in arr4 is random.int arr4[4]={0};